# Как узнать текущую директорию в С++ VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Здравствуйте, как узнать полный путь до приложения?
например: "c:\Test\Debug".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from ?

Comment: + по стандарту, насколько я понимаю, main-овый argv первым элементом содержит дирректорию в которой выполнялся запуск программы (argv[0])

Comment: Вы определитесь: полный путь до приложения или текущую директорию?

Comment: Что я не понимаю чем они отличаются...

Comment: @LabrobLabrob текущий каталог средствами WinAPI может быть изменен во время работы программы. А путь к модулю, из которого приложение запущено - в общем случае (или даже всегда) - нет.

Answer (score 1):

GetCurrentDirectory возвращает именно текущую директорию приложения.
GetModuleFileName - путь до файла, откуда приложение запущено

Comment: Как использовать их?
например:
std::string dircurrent = GetCurrentDirectory, но так не работает

Comment: Прочитайте документацию из MSDN, там и примеры есть. Более того, WinAPI не работает с std::string

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

using filesys = std::experemental::filesystem;
using std::string;

int main()
{
   string CurrentPath(filsys::current_path().generic_string());
   return 0;
}
```

Требует стандарта С++17

Comment: Вопрос был про "_полный путь до приложения_", а ваш ответ про текущий каталог. Это разные вещи совершенно.

Answer (score 1):

Путь передается как аргумент функции main.

```
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << argv[0] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

В argc количество аргументов, в argv[] сами аргументы.
Первый аргумент всегда, путь к .exe